# Spawning process in background on Jenkins - job that won't stay in queue

Tags: java, shell, jenkins, continuous-integration, wiremock

I want to make job on Jenkins that starts server (MockServer on WireMock).

Server is launched from *.jar file, from terminal like that.

```
java -jar serverLaunch.jar
```

It takes over my console. To avoid that I modify this and do:

```
java -jar serverLaunch.jar &>/dev/null &
```

And that works for me on my local PC. Now I want to move it to Jenkins.

If I try to do this from "Shell command" block in Jenkins Job then:

a) `java -jar serverLaunch.jar`

- I have task locked in queue in my Jenkins and I don't want that but server starts and works.

b) `java -jar serverLaunch.jar &>/dev/null &`

- Job ends with success but my server is not alive.

I have wrapped this command also in .sh script and .rb script. Any idea how to make it work?

---

I've tried this: 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build

And then in Jenkins "Shell script":

```
daemonize -E BUILD_ID=dontKillMe /bin/bash launch.sh
```

But it also passes but server is not alive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to check "Inject environment variables to the build process" and add:

> BUILD_ID=dontKillMe

Now it is working.

Comment: Setting BUILD_ID=dontKillMe or JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe doesn't work for me. Any suggestions on how to run jetty server or any shell command in background as daemon.

Answer (score -1):

Try using nohup e.g.:

`nohup java -jar serverLaunch.jar &`

That should prevent the process being terminated when the parent shell process exits (which I suspect is your problem).

Comment: When i do: `nohup java -jar serverLaunch.jar &` then task ends with success but I can't connect to server cuz its offline

Comment: nohup leaves a log file called nohup.out in the directory you started it from. Might be worth having a look at that to see if there's an error being reported.

Comment: no, it does not work. Jenkins kills the process that was started in job, even if it is daemonized with nohup (or 'daemonize' as the OP did) when the BUILD_ID env var is not set in job.

Answer (score -1):

Another effective approach would be to add a **post-build action** that executes a shell spawning the server.